# Returning reverse of a string using stack data structure

Tags: python, data-structures, stack

My program does return the reverse but in stack form. I want to convert it to a string type

```
def func(str_input):
    s1 = deque(str_input)
    s2 = deque()
    for i in range(len(str_input)):
        s2.append(s1[-1])
        s1.pop()
    return s2
func("hello")

#returns
```

deque(['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h'])

Also, would someone be able to explain why this solution "https://github.com/codebasics/data-structures-algorithms-python/blob/master/data_structures/5_Stack/Exercise/reverse_string.py" is ideal and optimal for this question? There seems to be a lot more code needed, but it is the popular solution,not sure why.

using str() also just keeps the "deque([list])" as a string. I just want the [list] part out so I can make it a string.

************************EDIT************************________________________
Ok I made some changes and it returns as a string, however my second question about the linked solution still stands.

Thank you in advance!

Here is my new solution

```
def somefuc(s):
    stack = deque(s)
    reverse = ''
    while len(stack) != 0:
        reverse +=stack.pop()
    return reverse
somefuc("hello")
```

Comment: Please edit your question to focus on one question only. Also make sure the essential information is embedded inside the question, not behind a link. Finally, asking for opinions about some code that is supposed to be popular, is off topic here, as it will be mostly about opinions.

Answer (score 0):

you don't want it to be a list? if so just use variable[::-1] it will return the given str but reversed

Comment: I can't use that. They want us to use a stack